# SQL Server 2008 View with LEFT OUTER JOIN fails on Entity Framework 4

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

- SQL Server 2008R2
- Entity Framework 4.x (early version)

I recently changed a view within a SQL Server 2088 R2 instance so that it now contains some `LEFT OUTER JOINS` instead of `INNER JOINS` which causes some fields to contains NULL now. That leaves with a exception that this fields are not allowed to be null cause they are entity keys.

[image: Please note that all files are Entity Keys]

Please note that all shown are required to be entity keys and that the image just showing a part of the whole view.

So am I doing anything totally wrong? Is there any fix around or do I have to life with it.

Here's one of the errors

> Error 213 Running transformation: Key Part: 'WorkStepId' for type
>   OrderSummary is not valid. All parts of the key must be non nullable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entity keys are not allowed to be NULL. Entity Framework has to be able to determine the uniqueness of an entity by a combination of one or more keys. I don't know your exact data circumstance, but there may be a way to work around this requirement, but it's not very clean.

A possible workaround is including logic in your view T-SQL to coalesce NULL values to a known "dummy" value. For instance, with your data above, you can set the two NULL values to be -1 on reads. However:

- You will have to use some sort of validation logic or stored procedure on save to prevent bad data being persisted to the database if you are doing writes.
- You have to be sure that only one row with two NULL values for WorkStepId and StepStatusId **per Id** can be returned.

Comment: That is the workaround I am using at this time. Checking for NULL an inserting a default value for that. I thought there is a way that the keys can be null. But as it sounds there is not...

Comment: Keys cannot be NULL because they are used to identify unique records. Because NULLs are never considered equal to other NULLs, they are problematic when used for identifying records or comparing keys.

Comment: Chances are EF has inferred the wrong value as an Entity Key. Just check the Entity and make sure the right fields are set as an Entity Key.

Answer (score 2):

EF generates the view to have all fields as the key and keys must have values. With the left join, you are going to have null columns. As a result, you will need to modify your now nullable type fields so that they aren't keys. I don't have a chance to test this locally at the moment, so I can't say if you just need to modify the conceptual level or need to go into the DBML to tweak the keys in the SSDL manually as well.

Comment: I tried this before but as it happen they need to be Keys. I thought there is a way that the keys can be null. But as it sounds there is not...